# Can't login to SQL Server using SQL Instance Name

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am new in SQL. I have installed SQL Sever 2016 & SSMS2016. My SQL server instance name is `MSSQLSERVER` (found it in Services list). When I am trying this servername  `RITWICK\MSSQLSERVER` , it's showing me incorrect.

But when I use just `RITWICK`, no problem.

Comment: You might have installed Default instance,which defaults to computer name

Comment: yes! May be.. But Can i change this?

Comment: MSSQLSERVER means its the default instance which means you connect to `RITWICK` (no instance name). You really need to post the specific error (even if its in another language). Why do you want to change this?

Comment: You can't..http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125437/how-to-convert-default-instance-to-named-instance-in-sql-server-2012

Comment: yes! I got that. :) Actually my concept is not clear in SQL.  :)